# Customizing the expandable list view in android with different structure for each child

Tags: android, xml, expandablelistview

I need to customize the expandable list view and each parent should have child with different structure,i.e in User Interface design.How can i do this task? Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) from android lib.
And please come back with more precise questions.

Answer (score 0):

Implement ExpandableListAdapter and have your array of items retain an int type. Then in the getChildView method just switch the type and inflate different layouts which you implemented previously.